# Vue.js: condition for class switching

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-statements

I already have an `active-class` for the item in a sidebar but how do I change the class of its label when the item is active? I need the `span` with the `class="u-label g-font-size-11 g-bg-primary g-rounded-20 g-px-7 g-ml-3"` to have the `class="u-label g-font-size-11 g-bg-primary g-rounded-20 g-px-7 g-ml-3 g-color-primary g-bg-white"` when I click on Notifications (make the item active).

```
<router-link to='/notifications'
                 class="list-group-item justify-content-between g-brd-none list-group-item-action"
                 active-class="active">
      <i class="icon-bell g-pos-rel g-top-1 g-mr-8"></i>
      Оповещения
      <span v-if="getNotificationsUnviewed > 0"
            class="u-label g-font-size-11 g-bg-primary g-rounded-20 g-px-7 g-ml-3">
             {{ getNotificationsUnviewed }}
      </span>
    </router-link>
```

Comment: can you make any live demo with minimal and clear requirement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `v-bind` to the class passing an object with true/false values, like follows:

```
<span v-if="getNotificationsUnviewed > 0"
    v-bind:class="{'u-label g-font-size-11 g-bg-primary g-rounded-20 g-px-7 g-ml-3' : true, 'g-color-primary g-bg-white' : isActive}">
         {{ getNotificationsUnviewed }}
  </span>
```

Let's have a look at what's inside the `:class`:

```
{
  "u-label g-font-size-11 g-bg-primary g-rounded-20 g-px-7 g-ml-3": true,
  "g-color-primary g-bg-white": isActive
}
```

The first class set will always be there as the value is `true`, the second will be set only if `isActive` is `true`.

Of course, your instance/component must have the isActive prop/data in order for this to work.

[See the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) for more info and alternative ways to doing so.

Comment: You can also have an unbound `class="u-label..."` for the unchanging values and only include the changeable ones in the `:class=`

Comment: Thank you for the information @RoyJ, I've always wondered if I could do that but I have never had time to test it out.